# How to delete an amCharts Chart

Tags: amcharts

I'm using the free version of AmCharts, and I have a simple question - how do you delete a Chart after it has been loaded?  I've searched the internet, but haven't come up on much.

Comment: Try to nullify the dataProvider.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to destroy the chart object, at all, call:

```
chart.clear();
```

and then null the chart variable:

```
chart = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, it helps, but I notice the chart is still listed in global AmCharts.charts array. I've asked AmCharts support, don't really want to remove it by hand…

Answer (score 0):

Also you can destroy(delete) the chart using these two simple methods

- chart is not a key word you can change whatever you want to name your chart for example my chart name is ActionPieChart `ActionPieChart.destroy();`

`chart.destroy();`

or

```
chart= null;
```

Comment: Does `chart.destroy() ` also call `series[i].destroy()` for all series in the chart?

Answer (score -1):

If by delete you mean delete from the page or to hide it, you could also use:

```
document.getElementById('[[ChartDIV]]').style.display = 'none';
```